# How to execute code when ReactJS component has been applied to DOM

Tags: reactjs

Actually I need to call `$('.datetime-picker').datetimepicker` each time component or it's diff has been flushed to DOM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `componentDidMount` and `componentDidUpdate` with `React.findDOMNode(this)`. Every time you rerender your component `componentDidUpdate` will be called and with `React.findDOMNode(this)` you can get the Component as DOM Object.

```
var DatePicker = new React.createClass({
  /*...*/
  componentDidMount: function() {
      $(React.findDOMNode(this)).datetimepicker();
  },
  componentDidUpdate: function() {
      $(React.findDOMNode(this)).datetimepicker();
  },
  render: function() {
     /* render */
  }
});
```

Comment: I tried that componentDidMount, but it alerts 0 components

```
    componentDidMount: () ->
      alert("Found " + $('.datetime-picker').length + ' inputs')
```
But if I execute alert from the console it shows 2 found components

Comment: Did you pass the prop className="datetime-picker"?

Comment: Ok, I tried that for the root component, not for that renders these divs. I've moved componentDidMount to the child and it worked! Thank you!